# PostgreSQL - ERROR: missing data for column "XX" SQL state: 22P04

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to import TXT file into the postgreSQL database table, but I am getting an error:

ERROR:

> missing data for column "bts_name"
>   SQL state: 22P04

My code is:

```
COPY indicadores2g (
  Daily,
  BTS_NAME,
  SITE_CODE
)
FROM 'C:\Users\Public\Documents\GEO_2G_CELL.txt' 
WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ' ' NULL AS '' ;
```

I know that the problem is in the txt file. In the txt file the last two line are blank (example), and when I remove them, the SQL run without problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3ryk.png)
My problem is I need to import every day. Is there any rule to put in my SQL code to run without problems?

Another way to run without problems is: Open TXT in excel and save as CSV. Can I do this automatically?

Comment: I'm assuming indicadores2g is a table already existing that has a not null on bts_name..   Instead, you could copy the data into a temporary table w/o limits on data loaded, then use a insert into select and exclude the nulls. and then drop the temporary table. or alter the table to allow the null, then delete those records after insert then activate the not null value again.  I prefer the temp table as it doesn't require changing existing table structure.

Answer (score 2):

Create simple batch (for example `inpfixer.bat`):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
  echo %%a
)
```

Then

```
COPY indicadores2g (
  Daily,
  BTS_NAME,
  SITE_CODE
)
FROM PROGRAM 'inpfixer.bat C:\Users\Public\Documents\GEO_2G_CELL.txt' 
WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ' ' NULL AS '' ;
```

Surely, `inpfixer.bat` should be available by `PATH`.

Disclaimer: Tested on the Wine.